# CUDA error: device-side assert triggered error on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deep-learning, pytorch

I try to train my model using PyTorch and a AWS EC2 Instance (g3s.xlarge), but there is a common error, the famous **RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered**

So have a more clear stacktrace, I run my sscript using CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1, and there is all the stacktrace I have:

```
  /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:53: lambda [](int)->auto::operator()(int)->auto: block: [0,0,0], thread: [44,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:53: lambda [](int)->auto::operator()(int)->auto: block: [0,0,0], thread: [26,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCCachingHostAllocator.cpp line=265 error=59 : device-side assert triggered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 367, in <module>
    backup_every=args.backup_every)
  File "train.py", line 267, in train
    if torch.isnan(loss):
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

This error came during the first epoch, or during the test of the first epoch (it depends)

I check my dataset and:
- There is no negative number
- All the output files are in Yolo format
- There is exactly the same number of files and labels

The number of classes I have is 17 (so I use 17 to generate my cfg, and I enter 17 in my .data file)

I can't identify where is the mistake, do you have any idea ?

**EDIT:**

I try to run the same command, with same dataset on CPU, and the following error happend:

```
Using CPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 367, in <module>
    backup_every=args.backup_every)
  File "train.py", line 198, in train
    load_darknet_weights(model, f'weights/{cutoff_name}')
  File "/home/florian/EYESR/eyesr-psycle/yolo_utils/models.py", line 278, in load_darknet_weights
    conv_w = torch.from_numpy(weights[ptr:ptr + num_w]).view_as(conv_layer.weight)
RuntimeError: shape '[512, 256, 3, 3]' is invalid for input of size 776331
```

Maybe when I resolve this, can affect the error on GPU ?